# How to transfer a lot of values beteen tables in a variable or array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables

I have two SQL tables. The first one structure is simple.

```
ID    Name
----------
```

The second one is simple too.

```
CommentID     Comment    CreatorID
----------------------------------
```

I want to show in my site all the comments that correspond with the "ID of user"

The problem is we have here a lot of ID and two different tables.

Something like this:

```
$1= $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id_user=220281");
$2=$1->fetch();
```

**But its impossible because** *id user* **is not on the** *comments* **table.**

Comment: You said you have "ID of the creator of the comment" on the comments table... Why not using it?

Comment: Its just an example..... Imagine i dont want to use it

Comment: Imagine the database will do anything you want if you'll just ask it nicely

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way to do this is to join the tables like this:

```
select
    users.name,
    comms.commentID,
    comms.comment
from
    userTable users
        join commentTable comms
            on users.ID=comms.ownersID
where
    users.id=1
```

This will return the users name in each row of data, but you don't need to use it in the output more than once.

It also sounds like you could use a few pointers on SQL queries. Do yourself a favour and [have a read of this article I put together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) a while back.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what he's asking

Comment: @BorisDetry I linked a lengthy document in my answer. Go have a read of it. It will explain a LOT of the things you probably want to know.

Answer (score 0):

A simple join will do the trick like this :

```
SELECT c.comment, u.user_name FROM 
    Users u 
JOIN
    Comments c ON 
    c.creator_id = u.user_id
WHERE 
    u.user_id=220281
```

fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3b28a/1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.* 
  FROM comments c
 INNER JOIN users u ON c.id_creator = u.id_user AND 
                       u.id_user = 220281
```